# read the source of any tool ( operator )

Tags: scripting, knife-tool

As you read in the title, i want to read the source of any tool,
but more expecificly i want want to read the code the kinfe_tool.

I can´t find the source to that tool, why??
(i have already try to use the edit operator addon, to serach for operators source)

Please help :D
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not all operators are written in python, and so you won't be able to get the source from them.

Fortunatelly, Blender is open source and you can look into the source code.
In case of the knife tool, you might want to check this folder:

https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/HEAD:/source/blender/editors/mesh